# Check if the string is a Palindrome using arrow Functiuons

Tags: javascript, html

I want to find if the user entered string is a Palindrome or not using arrow functions. But the code I have written is not showing an output....I dont understand whats wrong pls help....

```js
var name = prompt("Enter Name: ");
const isPalindrome = name => {

  const midPoint = name.length / 2;

  for (let i = 0; i < midPoint && i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name[i] != name[name.length - 1 - i]) {
      console.log(" Not Palindrome");
    }
  }
  console.log("Palindrome");
}
```

Comment: Nothing calls your function.

Comment: call your function to see the logs!

Answer (score 2):

You can check for palindrome without a for loop.

```
function isPalindrome(string) {
  const toArray = string.replace(/ /g, '').toLowerCase().split('');
  const reverseArray = toArray.slice().reverse();
  const original = toArray.join('');
  const reversed = reverseArray.join('');
  if (original === reversed) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  };
}
isPalindrome('WORD HERE');
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
isPalindrome(name)
```

under the code

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just to call the function with the user input.

Also remember to `return` from the function once the input is not found as a palindrome. Else function will log both `Not Palindrome` and `Palindrome` when the input is not palindrome

```js
var name = prompt("Enter Name: ");
const isPalindrome = name => {
  const midPoint = name.length / 2;
  for (let i = 0; i < midPoint && i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name[i] != name[name.length - 1 - i]) {
      console.log(" Not Palindrome");
      return;
    }
  }
  console.log("Palindrome");
}
isPalindrome(name);
```